# Using Nunjucks with Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

I am trying to use [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) as a template engine from [Express](https://expressjs.com/). I did this:

```
var express = require('express');
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var load = require('express-load');
var fs = require("fs");

var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

var env = nunjucks.configure(app.get('views'), {
    autoescape: true,
    express:    app 
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

But above code gives this error:

```
Template render error: compileExtends: cannot extend multiple times
   at Error.exports.TemplateError (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:49:19)
   at Object.extend.fail (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:49:15)
   at Object.extend.compileExtends (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:983:18)
   at Object.extend.compile (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:1083:22)
   at Object.extend._compileChildren (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:139:18)
   at Object.extend.compileRoot (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:1050:14)
   at Object.extend.compile (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:1083:22)
   at Object.module.exports.compile (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\compiler.js:1118:11)
   at Obj.extend._compile (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:414:35)
   at Obj.extend.compile (C:\my\nodejs\projects\\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:403:18)
```

Please tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 15):

I used it like this:

```
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    express: app,
    autoescape: true
});
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Worked out for me. Got it from the nunjucks website: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add my solution. I came across this same problem since the express generator does not have support for the nunjucks templating engine. As mentioned, you should import the `express` and `nunjucks` dependencies and then configure `nunjucks`.

```
const app = express();
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
nunjucks.configure('views', {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app
});
```

Next, you need to decide how you want to render your templates. You have the option of responding to HTTP requests by rending a simple string or file. However, assuming your project may grow at some point I believe it's better to take advantage of routing and middleware provided by express. Using the express generator, express provides two folders, **views**, and **routes**. Within the `app.js` file are two methods for responding to incoming requests.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Where indexRouter and usersRouter are both defined as follows:

```
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
```

This is telling express, when a request for "/" comes in, handle it with the `index.js` file in the **routes** folder. In the same manner, when a request for "/users" comes in, handle it with the `users.js` file in the **routes** folder. Since we are just trying to implement the nunjucks templating engine we can leave those lines as they are. It is important to understand that the `index.js` file in the **routes** folder will utilize the express Router, prepare the response, and render a file in the **views** folder with the same name. This means we need to create a file in the views folder called `index` - in order for the names to match.

The convention in the Nunjucks community is to use the `njk` extension. So, we will use `index.njk` as the name of our root page. Lastly, we need to let express know that it should be expecting the `njk` extension. This is because the `njk` extension is just a convention. We could just as easily use `.html` and as long as we have nunjucks configured and tell express to expect `html`. In `app.js`:

```
app.set('view engine', 'njk');
```

Now we can use the nunjucks templating engine and it will be compiled to HTML. I recommend creating a layout file and using nunjucks `{% block content %}` code-goes-here  `{% endblock %}` to create reusable components that can be inherited via Nunjuck's template inheritance, i.e. `{% extends "layout.njk" %}`

Nunjucks is an incredibly powerful templating engine with a robust set of feature. In my opinion, it is the most underrated templating engine. It's easy to use, extremely powerful, and extensible.

For more information regarding template inheritance, this is a helpful link from jinja2, from which nunjucks was ported, [click me](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#template-inheritance)!

If you want to see an example app I set up with Express 4, Nunjucks, and Winston for logging, you can find it on my [GitHub](https://github.com/EssenceOfChaos/express-nunjucks).

Answer (score 3):

This is like a basic configuration using **express js**, you could do something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const app = express();

nunjucks.configure('views',{
    autoescape:true,
    express:app
});

app.set('views','./views'); // <--Path to your views folder

app.get('/',(request,response)=>{
    response.render('some-view.html');
});
```

for more references take a look at the [official documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to place your templates folder on ${pwd}/teampltes

do like below.

```
//import
const path = require('path')

const express = require('express')
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks')


//init
const app = express()

nunjucks.configure(path.join(__dirname, 'templates'), {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I just setup nunjucks using the default way:

```
const express = require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

const app = express();
app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);
app.set('view engine','html');
app.set('views', globals.viewsDirectory);
```

"express": "4.16.4",
"nunjucks": "^3.2.3",

Comment: It still works even expressjs-5.0.0-alpha.5 and nunjucks 3.2.3